# Serve multiple angular docker containers with nginx on same server

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, virtual-machine

I have a VM running three docker containers (2 angular apps) and each container has his own nginx config. The VM itself has also an nginx config that handles the SSL and will forward traffic to each docker container, here are the configs:

host nginx:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.net;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert_net_combined.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.net.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;  # Docker container is on the same server
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /example-backoffice {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;  # backoffice app docker container     
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location ~ /myapi/api/(.*) {
        proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xx.x:8080/myapi/api/v1/$1$is_args$args;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
    }
}
```

nginx for angular app docker container 1 (port 8000):

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    listen [::]:8000;

    server_name localhost;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/;

    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    location /example/ {
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location / {
        port_in_redirect off;
        rewrite ^/$ /example/ redirect;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        internal;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        internal;
    }

    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_send_timeout 300;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    send_timeout 300;
    keepalive_timeout 300;
}
```

nginx for angular app docker container 2 (port 8001):

```
server {
    listen 8001;
    listen [::]:8001;

    server_name localhost;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/;

    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    location /example-backoffice/ {
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location / {
        port_in_redirect off;
        rewrite ^/$ /example-backoffice/ redirect;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        internal;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        internal;
    }

    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_send_timeout 300;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    send_timeout 300;
    keepalive_timeout 300;
}
```

As you can see both angular app nginx config are almost identical only difference is the port they are listening (8000 and 8001) and the specific url.

What I want to achieve is:

- https://example.net/ => display the content of container exposed on port 8000
- https://example.net/example-backoffice => display the content of
  container exposed on port 8001

Right now if I navigate to `https://example.net/` it works well and displays the correct container content, but if I navigate to `https://example.net/example-backoffice` I get a blank page, the http call it self is successful and seams to get the `index.html` file but the following https calls to the the app content in the container fail:

- https://example.net/example-backoffice/ (304 Not Modified - Green)
- https://example.net/main.d4bbda5673c5086d.js (404 Not Found)
- https://example.net/styles.0aa8f8d7356e66b7.css (404 Not Found)
- https://example.net/polyfills.fdbbbb0d712bdd48.js (404 Not Found)
- https://example.net/runtime.57c2f3dbcc185f24.js (404 Not Found)

I assume it fails since when trying to get the content of the angular app inside the docker container on port 8001 in `/usr/share/nginx/html/` it fails since it makes the call to `https://example.net/` and not `https://example.net/example-backoffice` which will try to get the content for 8001 from 8000.

so right now the config almost fully works except for this final redirect, but I can't figure out what I am missing, and any help would be appreciated.

Note: if more details are needed let me know

Containers running in the VM: (docker ps) - all running on the same docker network

- 80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8001->8001/tcp, :::8001->8001/tcp   bo-frontend
- 80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp   frontend
- 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp           backend

Angular app baseHrefs:

- port 8000 container: `<base href="/example">`
- port 8001 container: `<base href="/example-backoffice">`

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up finding a solution and I will leave it here in case it's usefull for someone else as well.

Basically the problem was in the config of nginx in angular apps docker containers, especifically in this block:

```
location /example-backoffice/ {
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

This config was trying to serve the files under /usr/share/nginx/html/. however, the actual config for to the app was trying to get the files from `/usr/share/nginx/html/example-backoffice/` so an alias was needed and this is the final result:

```
location /example-backoffice/ {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

The alias directive allows to adjust the file system path to locate files by specifying alias `/usr/share/nginx/html/` it effectively ignores the location block path (`/example-backoffice/`) when looking for files and to use `/usr/share/nginx/html/` as the base path.

the other part of the solution was updated the angular apps base href in the `index.html` file from:
`<base href="/example-backoffice">` to `<base href="/example-backoffice/">`
and also on the angular.json file:

```
"projects": {
    "example": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/example/",
            "baseHref": "/example/",
          }
        }
      }
   }
}
```